# Proxying with Generics

Tags: java, generics, proxy-classes

I use `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` to proxy objects.

I have this class:

```
public class TransportableImpl extends Transportable{
  public class OrderInvoker extends InvocationHandler{
           ...
  }
}
```

Here i build the Proxy:

```
Transportable t = new TransportableImpl();
Order myOrder = new OrderImpl();
Class proxyClass = Proxy.getProxyClass(getClass().getClassLoader(), Transportable.class, Order.class);
Object serializable = proxyClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{InvocationHandler.class}).newInstance(t.new OrderInvoker(myOrder));
```

Problem is: Class is raw type and

```
Class<? extends Order & Transportable> proxyClass =
     (Class<? extends Order & Transportable>) 
     Proxy.getProxyClass(getClass().getClassLoader(), 
     Transportable.class, Order.class);
```

is hard to read.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the issue that it's hard to read?

Comment: Yes. And `Class<?>` is not precisely.

Comment: Counter question: what would you like to write, i.e. what would you consider precise enough and yet easy to read? Can you provide some pseudo code which would help us understand what you're aiming at?

Comment: If it's about readability, I would suggest to move this question to CodeReview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, is codereview new?

Comment: The fact that you are using a raw class is only a problem if you were planning on using the generic type arguments, but I don't see how.

Comment: `Class<? extends Order & Transportable>` is invalid syntax anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Proxy#getProxyClass(ClassLoader, Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#getProxyClass%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class...%29) method is declared as

```
public static Class<?> getProxyClass(ClassLoader loader,
                                     Class<?>... interfaces)
```

Its return type is therefore `Class<?>`. The normal syntax would be

```
Class proxyClass<?> = Proxy.getProxyClass(getClass().getClassLoader(), Transportable.class, Order.class);
```

Technically you could do (with a warning)

```
public <T extends Order & Transportable> void doSomething() {
    Class<T> proxyClass = (Class<T>) Proxy.getProxyClass(Driver.class.getClassLoader(),
            Transportable.class, Order.class);
}
```

but that gains you nothing as you will pretty much never need to use that `T` variable. The [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class provides very little methods that makes use of it, namely [`getConstructor(Class...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) and [`newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29). But again, the whole point of reflection is that you only know the class types at run time, not at compile time where generics are useful.

Comment: Yes, thats it. I named it PROXY instead of T.